# Inserting a variable into a string

Tags: javascript, html, json, variables

I want to localize a json object by variable. For this I want to insert a html given variable into a json path as string.

I have a json file with a list of actors

```
"actors":{
    "Pete":{
      "status": "dead",
    },
    "Anna":{
      "status": "alive",
    },
    "Hans":{
      "status": "alive",
    },
    "Fred":{
      "status": "somewhat alive",
    }}
```

This file is used for foundryvtt as language file.

Now I want to access the data of the users by using the json path with [their html handlebar](https://foundryvtt.com/article/localization/).

```
{{localize 'actors.Pete.status'}}
```

which pushes the json path as string to a method which returns the json element.

This works perfectly and outputs: **dead**

Now I am trying to input a variable into the path. Which would look something like this:

```
{{localize 'actors.Variable.status'}}
```

My problem is, that the Variable is called similar as the json element:

```
{{user.name}}
```

which would output one of the names in the list, of course inputting this directly into the handlebar doesn't work.

```
{{localize 'actors.{{user.name}}.status'}}
```

I would love a simple and lightweight solution to this problem. Or some comments on my solution ;)

At the moment I am using some script with their java handlebar.

```
<input id="lan-name" name="name" type="text" value= "{{user.name}}" placeholder="Missing Translation for {{user.name}}"/>
<script>
   document.getElementById("lan-name").value = game.i18n.localize("actors.{{user.name}}.status");
</script>
```

But I only analyse code patterns and barely understand them.
Happy about any comments and pointers. Thanks in advance :D

Comment: 1. Java is a completely separate and very different language 2. use template literals: `game.i18n.localize(\`actors.${user.name}.name\`)` (note that your question seems to boil down to *inserting a variable into a string*, which it is much much easier to find existing solutions for)

Comment: shouldn't `actors.Pete.age` be `actors.Pete.status`?

Comment: @GrafiCode jup you are right, whanted to use a simple template but messed up. Now fixed.

Comment: @ChrisG wow jea.... thx, changed header and am looking into it :)